# finding examples in which the density is not defined

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

here m is the n-dimensional Lesbegue measure. Could anyone suggest me some Borel set E and a point x such that the limit does not exist?

Answer (score 2):

In dimension one, a simple example would be
$$ E = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} [(1/3)^{2n+1},(1/3)^{2n}] $$

When $r$ is an *even* power of $1/3$ the fraction in the definition is at least $2/6$; when it is an *odd* power of $1/3$ the fraction is at most $1/6$.

Comment: here, is the point 'x' zero?

Comment: @Merideth: Yes, of course.