# Finding examples in which the density is not defined - follow up

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the (only) solution to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160208/finding-examples-in-which-the-density-is-not-defined):

> In dimension one, a simple example would be
> $$ E = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} [(1/3)^{2n+1},(1/3)^{2n}] $$
>
> When $r$ is an *even* power of $1/3$ the fraction in the definition is at least $2/6$; when it is an *odd* power of $1/3$ the fraction is at most $1/6$.

First, how is the set $E$ in the solution a Borel set? I can prove that its Borel if I can show that $E$ is either closed or open (there are other ways of showing this, too, of course), but I don't think $E$ is either closed or open. How can I shows that $E$ is Borel?

Second, how exactly is the density of the proposed set $E$ undefined at $x=0$? I know for this to be true, we would need to show that the quantity $$\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{|E \cap (-t, t)|}{2t}$$ is undefined. I am guessing that this boils down to showing that $\lim\limits_{t \downarrow 0} |E \cap (-t, t)|$ is finite and non-zero. However, it appears to me that for all $t, E \cap (-t, t) = \emptyset$ so that $\lim\limits_{t \downarrow 0} |E \cap (-t, t)| = 0$. Where am I going wrong?

**Edit 1:** The smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$ containing all open subsets of $\mathbb R$ is called the collection of Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$. An element of this $\sigma$-algebra is called a Borel set.

**Edit 2:** Can someone please explain what the author meant by the following in their answer:

> When $r$ is an *even* power of $1/3$ the fraction in the definition is at least $2/6$; when it is an *odd* power of $1/3$ the fraction is at most $1/6$.

By $r$, did they mean $n$?

Comment: @Joe Please see my edit for the definition of Borel sets.  I am using the definition of $\sigma$-algebra that is in this link: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sigma-Algebra.html.

Comment: So the collection of Borel sets is a $\sigma$-algebra, and it contains all open subsets. What is a $\sigma$-algebra closed under?

Comment: @Joe It's closed under the union operation. Thanks, I see how I can prove that $E$ is a Borel set.

Comment: If you look at the original question, the $r$ was in $B(r,x)$, so the $r$ was what you are calling $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?
$$
E = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} \big[(1/3)^{2n+1},(1/3)^{2n}\big]
$$
Yes, this is a Borel set.  Try harder to prove it.

---

No, $E \cap (-t, t) \ne \emptyset$.

---

To work on
$$
\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{|E \cap (-t, t)|}{2t}
$$
try computing $|E \cap (-t, t)|$ when $t=1/3^{2n}$ for some $n$ and when
$t=1/3^{2n+1}$ for some $n$.

Comment: @GEdgar I found that when $t=1/3^{2n}$, we get $|E\cap (-t, t)| = 2/3^{2n+1}$ for any $n$ I pick and when $t=1/3^{2n+1}$, we get $|E\cap (-t, t)| = 1//3^{2n+1}$ for any $n$. How should I proceed from here? Why is it valid to take $t=1/3^{2n}$ since $t$ is only a limiting variable?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson, I think your equal signs should be inequalities. For example, when $t=(1/3)^0=1$, $|E\cap (-1,1)| >2/3$, and when $t=(1/3)^1$, $|E\cap (-1/3,1/3)| <1/9$. How you proceed is by next dividing by $|(-t,t)|$. You are not restricting $t$ to equal $(1/3)^{2n}$ or $(1/3)^{2n+1}$ in the limit, but you are observing what happens when it does, which should show that the limit does not exist.

Comment: @Joe Thanks so much for all the feedback! One small question: how is $|E \cap (-t, t)| > 2/3$? When I computed this, I got $|E \cap (-t, t)| =  |\cup_{n\in\mathbb N} [(1/3)^{2n+1},(1/3)^{2n}] \cap (-1, 1)| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{2n}} - \frac{1}{3^{2n+1}} = \frac{2}{3} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{2n}} =  \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1-1/9} = \frac{1}{12},$ which doesn't obey the inequality you mentioned.

Comment: You started your sum for $E$ from $n=1$, but you have $t=1=(1/3)^0$. You need to use $t=(1/3)^{2n}$ or $t=(1/3)^{2n+1}$ to see the behavior described in that answer. I took $0\in \mathbb{N}$ to be the first even number, and $[1/3,1)\subset E\cap(-1,1)$ so $|E\cap(-1,1)|>2/3$. If you don't consider 0 a natural number, then you would have 2 as the first even example, so $t=(1/3)^4$, and $[(1/3)^5,(1/3)^4)\subset E\cap(-(1/3)^4,(1/3)^4)$, so $|E\cap(-(1/3)^4,(1/3)^4)|>2(1/3)^5$ and the denominator is now $2(1/3)^4$ instead of $2$, so the fraction is still greater than $1/3$.

Comment: Also, note that that answer is not using the exact size of $E\cap(-t,t)$, but is using a bound. When $t=(1/3)^{2n}$ it is saying that the size of $E\cap(-t,t)$ is greater than $2(1/3)^{2n}$, since $[(1/3)^{2n+1},(1/3)^{2n})\subset E\cap(-t,t)$. When $t=(1/3)^{2n+1}$ it is saying that the size of $E\cap(-t,t)$ is less than $(1/3)^{2n+2}$, since $E\cap(-t,t) \subset (0,(1/3)^{2n+2})$.